# Extracting non jpeg images from pdfs with iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, jpeg, extract

I'm able to extract images from pdfs using the RenderListener class which seems to only support JPEG, any other type throws an error. Another approach I was considering is looping through the XObjects but I can't get the actual content from them. Is there any work around to extracting other image types from a PDF?

Comment: JPEG is the only 'true file format' that can be embedded wholly into a PDF; the rest are just plain bits (possibly compressed as well). So technically there are no other "image types" to extract.

Comment: The render listener also supports other file formats, usually png for those plain bits. If you get errors, simply show your code and share a sample PDF so we can reproduce your problems and help.

Comment: @mkl this is the error iam getting.                                                          Unhandled Exception: iTextSharp.text.exception.UnsupportedPdfException: The color space [/Indexed, /DeviceCMYK, /219, 95 0 R] is not supported.

Comment: Ah, ok, for iText to export a bitmap image as png, the colorspace needs to be simple, e.g. simply RGB, or simply CMYK, or simply grayscale. You have a special colorspace, an indexed colorspace, which iText does not support for out-of-the-box image extraction.

Comment: @mkl do you know if its possible for any workaround since iText does not support that?

Comment: I have to correct my recent comment. iText PNG export does not have issues with the colorspace being indexed but with the base colorspace being CMYK. Looking at the PNG specification this makes sense: It only knows color types 0, 2, 3, 4, and 6 in which *Each pixel is a grayscale sample / an R,G,B triple / a palette index / a grayscale sample,
                       followed by an alpha sample / an R,G,B triple,
                       followed by an alpha sample*, and a palette entry is and R, G, B triple.

Comment: iText Tiff export, on the other hand, supports CMYK but not indexed. A workaround, therefore, would be to replace the `getImage()` call by an own method which analyses the stream and creates an image in an appropriate format. A starting point would be to try to expand the indexed CMYK stream to a flat CMYK stream which can be stored as a Tiff as in `PdfImageObject.decodeImageBytes()`.